# Colly not finding any links

Tags: go, web-scraping

I've done a few programs like this before in basically the same fashion (just different domains), however this time, colly isn't finding a single link and just quits after visiting the first page. Can anyone see what's wrong?
*NOTE: there are parts of the program I have omitted for clarity about the topic at hand.

*EDIT: I have found the problem but not a solution. Running `curl https://trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/research-and-analysis/threat-reports` returns a 301 permanently moved error in the terminal, but connecting to the same link in the browser gets the page I want. Why is THIS happening and how do  I fix it?

*EDIT2: I have found that making the command `curl -L` makes curl follow redirects - which then spits out the webpage I need. However, how do I translate that to colly? Because colly is still picking up the 301 error.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
    /* only navigate to links within these paths */
    tld1 := "/vinfo/us/security/research-and-analysis/threat-reports"

    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("trendmicro.com", "documents.trendmicro.com"),
    )

    c.OnHTML("a[href]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        link := e.Attr("href")
        fmt.Printf("Link found: %q -> %s\n", e.Text, link)
        if strings.Contains(link, tld1) {
            c.Visit(e.Request.AbsoluteURL(link))
        }
    })

    c.OnRequest(func(r * colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL.String())
    })

    c.Visit("https://trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/research-and-analysis/threat-reports")
}
```

Comment: Look at the response directly, there aren't any links in there.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry. Can you expand on that? What part of the code is affected? I don't have a c.OnResponse() section in the code

Comment: No, but you could probably (not familiar with colly myself) add one, or just curl the url and see what the response is. It returns a 301 to different domain.

Comment: Wow you're right. When I curl the link it returns a 301 to permanently moved - but pasting the link in a browser connects right away to the page I want! Is there some sort of bot detection in play here?

Comment: No, your browser just follows the redirection, like it's supposed to; colly doesn't, probably because of restrictions you've put on the domains (or maybe it doesn't follow redirects by default? you'd have to read the docs)

Comment: I ended up figuring it out and posting my answer below, thanks @JimB

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I plugged my link https://trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/research-and-analysis/threat-reports into https://wheregoes.com/retracer.php to find where the 301 redirects to, only to find out it prepends a www. to the beginning of the link. Adding the www. to the beginning of the initial `c.Visit` string and to the `c.AllowedDomains` sections worked like a charm